# Laravel - Mail class Exception

Tags: php, email, laravel-4

I need to send email within my app and this is my code:

```
if( $agent->save() )
        {
            //Preparo la mail da inviare con i dati di login
            $data = [
                'nome' => $input['nome'],
                'cognome' => $input['cognome'],
                'email' => $input['email'],
                'password' => $input['password']
            ];

            //ATTENZIONE
            //Questo è da rimuovere in produzione, finge di inviare la mail
            Mail::pretend(); 

            //Recuero il template e passo alla funzione i dati
            Mail::send('emails.agents.registration', $data, function($message) use ($data)
            {                           
                $message->to( $data['email'], $data['nome'].' '.$data['cognome'] )->subject('Benvenuto!');
            });

            return Redirect::action('admin.agents.index')->with('positive_flash_message', 'Agente inserito correttamente.');
        }
```

As you can see I have use the Mail::pretend to avoid the email send in development, the problem is that I get this error every time I try to send an email:

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Mail\Message::$email (View: /var/www/progetti/app/views/emails/agents/registration.blade.php)
```

nd this is my blade view:

```
Email: {{ $message->email }}
Password: {{ $message->password }}
```

What's wrong with $message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your calling the wrong values in the view. It should be:

```
Email: {{ $email }}
Password: {{ $password }}
```

As a side point - you should not be calling `Mail::pretend()` in your code. You should be configuring this as part of your environment setup, so that while in dev mode, the mail pretend is set to true, and in production it is set to false.

Comment: Thanks, now it works and thansk for your clue about the environments, I will do it right now